# Change eth settings before udev loads

Tags: centos, udev, mac-address

I have a custom version of CENTOS that I'm importing into Hyper-V on a Windows Server.
Whenever I import it however, the mac addresses of eth1 and eth2 are now different. So they get incremented to eth3 and eth4.

I've written a script that can detect when this happens and edit the `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net-rules` file so that it reverts to eth1 and eth2 after a reboot.

But a better way of doing this, I think, would be to find the new mac addresses early at boot, then edit my `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net-rules` file **before** udev loads at all. That way it'll boot with the recommended settings.

Static mac addresses are not an option for this.

Is there a way for me to get the new mac addresses before they're assigned? Also is there a way to predict which eth they're going to be assigned to?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the answer. But I solved my problem by removing the information about all of the devices in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net-rules` before rebooting. The file just contained:

"# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules

# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.

#

# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single

# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key."

Then upon reboot, my devices were set to eth0 and eth1 again.